# Hashing table doing linear probing with "while" loop

Tags: python

So I'm supposed to create a hash function that would add elements from L into my hash table using linear probing.
So according to linear probing, if the index is not empty, I should move to the next index and so on, but when I tried to write my code using a `while` loop, the program didn't stop.

The output should be:

```
{0: 45, 1: 'empty', 2: 'empty', 3: 12, 4: 4, 5: 3, 6: 78, 7: 'empty', 8: 'empty', 9: 'empty', 10: 'empty'}
```

My first idea was the following: but it doesn't make any sense though:

```
if hash_table[key] == 'empty':
    hash_table[key] = i
elif hash_table[key] !='empty':
    while hash_table[key]!='empty':
        hash_table[key]=+1
    if hash_table[key]=="empty":
        hash_table[key]=I
```

My code:

```
def hashing(L):
    hash_table={0:'empty',1:'empty',2:'empty',3:'empty',4:'empty',5:'empty',6:'empty',
                7:'empty',8:'empty',9:'empty',10:'empty'}

    for i in L:
        key=i%9
        if hash_table[key]=='empty':
            hash_table[key]=i
        elif hash_table[key]!='empty':
            hash_table[key+1]=i

    return hash_table


#code to test your implementation
if __name__ == '__main__':
    L=[4,78,45,12,3]
    print(hashing(L))
```

Comment: is this a class assignment?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your attempt is that if the first statement (meaning your key value) is not empty, you need to loop through the hash function in ascending order to find an empty spot, also replacing the string 'empty' with `None` will be easier.

Instead of using an `elif` you can you  use another for loop to increment the key values, like so:

```
def hashing(L):
    hash_table={0: None,1:None,2:None,3:None,4:None,5:None,6:None,7:None,8:None,9:None,10:None}

for val in L:
    key=val%9
    if hash_table[key] == None:
        hash_table[key]=val
    else:
        for i in range(len(hash_table.keys())):
            if hash_table[key+i] == None:
                hash_table[key+i] = val
                break

    
return hash_table
```

is a possible solution...

Comment: the output should be: {0: 45, 1: 'empty', 2: 'empty', 3: 12, 4: 4, 5: 3, 6: 78, 7: 'empty', 8: 'empty', 9: 'empty', 10: 'empty'}

Comment: your code is giving this as an output {0: 45, 1: 45, 2: None, 3: 12, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 78, 7: 78, 8: 12, 9: 3, 10: None}

Comment: woops - fixed the problem, missed an else statement

Comment: What happens when 4 distinct keys hash to 8?

Comment: well it depends how you want to handle collisions - 
as I said before the Linear probing is supposed to circulate through the whole hash-table until it finds an empty place, and it it doesn't it should raise and error. BUT if you handle collisions using lets say linked lists, then it doesn't matter how many values are stored on the same key, (unless you have a max size on the hashtable)

Comment: I will add and say that what I've created works on this simple example.
A hash table can be general (for most used cases) or tailor made for a specific data set.
so it really depends on your data.
in this case I'd advise to improve the for loop and hash the value again after incrementing the value by one, and then you'll eventually enter this consistent loop of iterating through the whole hash table.

Comment: Your code will crash for `[8, 17, 26, 35]`. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a course assignment, but you probably need something like :

```
for i in L:
      key=i%9
      while hash_table[key]!='empty':
        key += 1
      hash_table[key]=i
```

You should probably add bound check too...

Comment: Note : this is not going to get a usefull hash table...